# How to bind data dynamically using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts

I want to dynamically bind data using `Chart.js`.

Initially, I was able to bind statically data using codes inside template. Now, I want to dynamically bind data given by API request. However, after the data is reponsed, the browser does not draw the chart again, so it does not bind the data given by api request.

Currently, I am drawing a chart like below (by setting data attribute on html template)

```
<canvas data-chart=“bar”
data-animation=“false”
data-labels=‘[“월”, “화”, “수”, “목”, “금”, “토”,“일”]’
data-values=‘[{“label”: “이번 주“, “backgroundColor”: “#d9230f ”, “borderColor”: “#d9230f ”, “data”: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}, {“label”: “저번 주“, “backgroundColor”: “#d9831f ”, “borderColor”: “#d9831f ”, “data”: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}]’
data-tooltips=‘{“mode”: “label”}’
data-hide=‘[“gridLinesX”, “legend”]’ height=“150"
id=“orders-week-chart”></canvas>
```

With html code above, I used javascript to bind data, however, a browser does not repaint the chart.

So I want to bind data to `data-values` (initally set to 0's) when the page is loaded and the data is given by api request.

This is the solution I can think of.

Any advice or suggestion to bind data to chart dynamically would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you use javascript to render new data every time your event is triggered?